# How to combine tables in linux for big-data?

Tags: text-processing

I have ~30 files, each individual file contains two columns 1st is an ID column and 2nd is number.I want to combine all the files in to one file, not by simple concatenation command.In a separate file, I need all the ID's in 1 column and the corresponding value for the each ID in their respective column. If one ID doesn't present in any of the files the score can be given zero.

The `ID` column doesn't have same number of entries it differs alot from each file.

Example individual files

- 10_S9.counts.matrix

  ```
     ID             10_S9
     TRI_DN0_c0_g1   12717.85
     TRI_DN100000_c0_g1  93.65
     TRI_DN100001_c0_g1  110.58
     TRI_DN100002_c0_g1  80.76
     TRI_DN100003_c0_g1  386.84
     TRI_DN100004_c0_g1  137.85
     TRI_DN100005_c0_g1  52.14
     TRI_DN100006_c0_g1  87.19
     TRI_DN100009_c0_g1  27.88
  ```
- 11_S13.counts.matrix

  ```
     ID          11_S13
     TRI_DN0_c0_g1   22358.82
     TRI_DN0_c2_g1   164.98
     TRI_DN100000_c0_g1  164.40
     TRI_DN100001_c0_g1  140.92
     TRI_DN100002_c0_g1  196.00
     TRI_DN100003_c0_g1  46.94
     TRI_DN100004_c0_g1  71.21
     TRI_DN100005_c0_g1  106.48
     TRI_DN100006_c0_g1  28.96
  ```
- 12_S17.counts.matrix

  ```
     ID        12_S17
     TRI_DN0_c0_g1   11195.36
     TRI_DN0_c1_g1   490.24
     TRI_DN0_c2_g1   64.11
     TRI_DN0_c3_g1   14459.43
     TRI_DN0_c4_g1   4173.92
     TRI_DN0_c5_g1   4015.54
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   194.56
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   26.99
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   1078.54
  ```
- 13_S21.counts.matrix

  ```
     ID        13_S21
     TRI_DN0_c0_g1   40754.51
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   85.85
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   80.68
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   78.92
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   101.48
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   94.66
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   189.68
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   39.68
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   199.86
  ```
- 14_S26.counts.matrix

  ```
     ID       14_S26
     TRI_DN0_c0_g1   35750.85
     TRI_DN0_c0_g2   1521.63
     TRI_DN0_c0_g3   8969.77
     TRI_DN0_c1_g1   13918.85
     TRI_DN0_c1_g2   797.95
     TRI_DN0_c2_g1   83624.41
     TRI_DN0_c3_g1   669.73
     TRI_DN0_c4_g1   53.83
     TRI_DN1_c0_g1   235.10
  ```
- The final table should be like this:

  ```
         ID             10_S9    11_S13  12_S17  13_S21  14_S26 

     TRI_DN0_c0_g1      334.30    678    98.0     56.0    98.0
  *  TRI_DN0_c1_g1      200.44     0     859.36  89.03     0
     TRI_DN0_c2_g1       12.32    34     12.56    64.6    78.9
  *  TRI_DN100000_c0_g1  20.79     0       0       0        0
     TRI_DN100001_c0_g1  24.18    34.3    12.56    64.6    78.9
     TRI_DN100002_c0_g1  73.50    67.8    98.8     56.0    98.0
  *  TRI_DN100003_c0_g1  162.44   10.25   456.23  98.45     0
     TRI_DN100004_c0_g1  55.98    3.34    6.78    98.0      1.5
     TRI_DN100005_c0_g1  77.86    55.98    3.34   73.50    67.8
  ```

where the `*` symbol represents the ID is present only in 10_S9,12_S17,13_S21 and absent in 11_S13,14_S26 the given score is zero "0".

Please help me, to generate this table/matrix.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us exact examples of your files. Are the lines like `==> 12_S17.counts.matrix <==` part of your file? If not, please remove them. Do all of your lines start with empty spaces? If not, please remove those as well.  We need to know exactly what the files look like in order to be able to help you.

Comment: So the output is a 31-column file, with a header for each column derived from the 2nd column of each input file. Two issues there: (1) What to do with any vacant cells? (2) What to do with multiple entries for the same cell?

Comment: Clarification: What should be done if there are multiple values with the same ID as it is for 13_S21 with the ID TRI_DN1_c0_g1? Multiple listings? Minimum? Maximum? Median? Average?

Comment: Additional information please: (1) Total data size -- it would be convenient to get it all into memory at once. (2) Input column separator is ?? (3) Output column separator is ??

Comment: HI, I removed the lines as @terdon suggestion.

Comment: The each individual matrix file ranges from 3.5 to 4.9 Mb. Memory is not a problem, these only contain text. space/tab operator @Paul.

Comment: If their is same ID with multiple that wont be a problem. I'm not looking for common ones across all the files. I just want to combine all the ID's into one file in a single column and to assign respective value in the sample column (10_S9    11_S13  12_S17  13_S21  14_S26) @jmf7.

Comment: I tried with cut and paste commands it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

a tcsh script that can be run with " tcsh script.csh"

```
#script.csh

    egrep -v '==>|ID' *.matrix | sort -k2,2 -k1,1 | sed -e's/\.counts.matrix:/ /g' | sort -k2,2 -u | awk '{printf("   %s   0.0\n",$2)}' > allIDs.txt
  
    foreach xx ( ` ls -1d *.matrix ` )
      set yy = ` echo $xx | sed -e's/matrix/matrix.tmp/g' `
      cat $xx allIDs.txt | xargs -L1 | sort -k1,1 -k2,2gr | awk 'BEGIN {last="xxx"} { if ( $1 != last ) printf(" %s\n",$0) ; last=$1}' > $yy
    end

    ( echo '  ID  '; ls -1d *.counts.matrix.tmp | sed -e's/.counts.matrix.tmp//g' | sort -k1,1 ) | xargs | sed -e's/ /     /g' -e's/ID /      ID       /g' > table.txt
    egrep -v '==>|ID' *.matrix.tmp |  sort -k2,2 -k1,1 -k3,3gr | sed -e's/.counts.matrix.tmp//g'   | awk 'BEGIN {last="xxx"} { if ($2!=last) { if (last != "xxx") printf("\n"); printf("%s    ",$2);} printf("%s     ",$3); last=$2} END{printf("\n")}' >> table.txt
    unset xx yy
```

puts output into a file "table.txt" but the formatting is not great.
Only writes out the maximum of multiple values.
Also creates junk ".matrix.tmp" files as intermediates.
A quick script that may do the job, but not the greatest.

Also presumes file names are consistent with the column headings in the output file.

Comment: A bug if any entries are negative only, and so you'd have to switch to all positive entries.  Negative entries did not seem to be a case from the examples.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work what actually I'm expecting.Any way thanks for the suggestions.